# Calling a function on an image after it is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixastic

I am trying to dynamically add a bunch of images to my page in `jQuery`, and then use the [pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/) image processing library to modify them.  The user enters some search criteria, the list of image URLs is returned I append them to my content area and then try to do something- invert them for example.  Here is my code:

```
function loadImages() {
$.ajax( {
    type: "POST",
    url: "/reporter/api/ezdz/getslides/",
    data: {
        'startDate': $( "#startdate" ).val(),
        'endDate': $( "#enddate" ).val()
    },
    success: function ( data ) {
        for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            var imgname = "imgename" + i;
            $( "#imagecontentarea" ).append( '<img id=' + imgname + ' src="' + data[i].ImageUrl + '" />' );
            $( imgname ).one( 'load', function () {
                $( imgname ).pixastic( "invert" );
            } );
        }
    }
} );
}
```

The images are returned just fine, and my load event is even fired... but the images don't change.

This code however works fine if I call it from document.ready:

```
$( "#imagecontentarea" ).append( '<img id="testimg" src="http://localhost/thumbnail.jpg" />' );
$("#testimg").one('load', function() {
    $( "#testimg" ).pixastic( "invert" );
});
```

I would prefer to operate on each image as it is loaded, rather than wait til they all load then start inverting them.  I looked at the [imagesloaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) library but it looks like that operates on a parent container (`?`).

Anyways, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877027/901048) might be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your success function to this:

```
success: function ( data ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var imgname = "imgename" + i;
        $( "#imagecontentarea" ).append( '<img id=' + imgname + ' src="' + data[i].ImageUrl + '" />' );
        (function (imgname) {$( imgname ).one( 'load', function () {
            $( imgname ).pixastic( "invert" );
        } );})(imgname);
    }
}
```

Your code was not saving `imgname` in the closure, so you were operating on the last name in the loop.

EDIT: Another possibility is to use a class:

```
success: function ( data ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var imgname = "imgename" + i;
        $( "#imagecontentarea" ).append( '<img class="imagename" id=' + imgname + ' src="' + data[i].ImageUrl + '" />' );
    }
    $(".imagename").one( 'load', function () {
        $(this).pixastic( "invert" );
    } );
}
```

Comment: Tried this- was unable to get it to work :(  Same behavior as above.

Comment: I just added another solution using a class, maybe that will work better.